# Natural key query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I was reading natural key in google, but could not found out if a table need natural key then how to alter table for natural key query in sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table needs some way to identify a row.

When you design a database, you identify one (maybe more) candidate keys on a table. This is  the natural key of that table.

At implementation time you may choose to use a surrogate key for architectural reasons. Your natural key is still there.

The natural or surrogate key is the primary key, with a unique constraint on another.

You don't add a natural key to an existing table: it is already there...